# How to allow local connections via Onion Pi?

Tags: configuration, raspberry-pi

Similar to [Access local router in Tor Browser?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4914/), but I'm using an [Onion Pi](https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi?view=all#install-tor). This unfortunately prevents some local uses such [WiFiKeyboard](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.volosyukivan) which sends typing from a laptop to an Android. I know that it's just a convenience feature, but I would like to learn how to set that up. Reading through the occurrences of `192.168` in [the torrc sample](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/plain/src/config/torrc.sample.in) and the [man page](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) didn't make the answer clear.

Therefore: Which `torrc` setting corresponds to the answer in the above referenced question (`options […] advanced […] network […] connection settings […] choice to not use a proxy for 192.168...)`? What do I have to set in order to allow local connections?

Answer (score 2):

The occurences in `torrc` are to :

1. Bind SOCKS listener to port 9100 on address 192.168.0.1 via `SOCKSPort 192.168.0.1:9100` directive
2. Allow connections from 192.168.0.0/16 subnet to the SOCKS proxy via `SOCKSPolicy accept 192.168.0.0/16`

The problem you're experiencing is that INSIDE a Wi-Fi network devices can't talk to the Raspberry Pi, i.e. the apps running on it. It's a firewall trouble and it has completely no link with Tor itself. If you're using IPTables, use them to fix it : `iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT` insert it BEFORE diverting rule. Also you may need to correct your diverting rule to not wrap-up everything, but only all not destinating to your local network(s), but just one ACCEPT rule should be fine if you don't have a complex firewall setup. Post your `iptables --list` or/and `iptables --all --list` here if you will have any further problems