# Exclude IP addresses - where has it gone?

Tags: proxy, ip-address

thanks for your time today.

I have recently reinstalled Tor and noticed the configuration to exclude IP addresses from the proxy has gone. This guide covers an older version.
[Access local router in Tor Browser?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4914/access-local-router-in-tor-browser/4946#4946)

I want an add-on (Synology download station) to access an internal IP address but for this to work I need to exclude it from the browsers usual behaviour.

Any help and advice would be really appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I asked your question on the [tor-talk mailing list](https://lists.torproject.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/tor-talk) and got the following reply from one of the creators of Tor itself:

> You should really avoid making exceptions to the proxy rules for Tor
>   Browser. If you let your browser connect to local services, that opens
>   the door for remote websites, which you access over Tor, to give you
>   instructions (e.g. via javascript, but not only via javascript) to
>   make local connections and then send that info back to the website.
>
> In the most benign case, you're setting yourself up with a tracking
>   marker ("there's that weird person who allowed connections to
>   192.168.1.1 again"). In worse cases, you're opening yourself up to permissions surprises and attacks that start with the word
>   "cross-site" or "cross-protocol".
>
> For an early example of a similar bug that bit Tor users, see
>   https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-announce/2007-September/000078.html
>
> All of that said, if you still want to shoot your feet off: in
>   **about:config**, there's a **network.proxy.no_proxies_on** option that you
>   can set.
>
> For even more details, new in ESR68, there is now a
>   network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost option, which we needed to fix
>   for Tor Browser: https://bugs.torproject.org/31065

So, with that answer, a best practice would be to use a standalone browser instance for local network access.

Comment: Apologies, I use the synology download station add-on to send torrents to the NAS to download them.
In a previous version of Tor I could configure to exlude IPs from the browser routing via the usual Tor/onion routes, updating the browser retained the configuration.
Since reinstalling Tor from new the functionality has gone.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only way you can achieve this is via *separate* router with Tor and some firewall rules. Closed-source solutions like Synology are almost always are just a pain in the ass when it comes to fine-grained controol **regardless** of their internal interfaces like Web GUI. You have to use a router, you must - actually