# Why can't I access localhost from Tor browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I want to access localhost from Tor browser but after I go to the `http://localhost:8000/` URL nothing happens. It's working fine on Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and other browsers. Why can't I access localhost from Tor browser?

Comment: Cause localhost is local to your computer, Tor is a public network that routes your traffic around the world. The network connections Tor browser makes are not local. Tor will not attempt any connections to private networks, or localhost. The browser connection leaves your computer and goes through 3 Tor relays and finally to the destination. That exit node (which can be anywhere in the world) cannot access "localhost" on your computer since it has zero knowledge about the request, only the destination and the relay it needs to send the response back to.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, tor “relocates” you so you can not see anything local. You can be in Mexico and in Russia on the next page, so that might be why. Tbh I don’t see the point of using thor for localhost projects. You can mod firefox

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answered.

See [Exclude IP addresses - where has it gone?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/20854/exclude-ip-addresses-where-has-it-gone/20868#20868)

I received the answer directly from Tor developers on the mailing list.